# Working without network on react app using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mocking, interceptor

I won't have network for the following days.

My web app is made of a django back and a react front (with axios for my request). About twenties requests are made from my front to my back. Is there an easy and quick way to save my requests and then mock them. I will work only on front side.

**I cannot run django back on my laptop**, I cannot mock my requests on back side.

I think I need sommething like this:

```sh
$ ls mocked_request
index.js
user.json
modules.json
cart.json
products.json
product1.json
product2.json
...

$ cat mocked_request/index.js
// {endpoint: res}
export default {
  user: './user.json',
  modules: './module.json',
  ...
}

$ cat http.js
import 'axios';
import mock from './mocked_request';

mock = // here something to intercept axios request and return my mocked data

export default mock;
```

then in my files replace `import axios` by `import axios from './http'`

Is there a simple way do achieve this. If so, how can I set up my mocked axios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) that allows to easily mock requests.
2. Use [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/) - Mock by intercepting requests on the network level. Seamlessly reuse the same mock definition for testing, development, and debugging.
3. Use [miragejs](https://miragejs.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) - Mirage is a JavaScript library that lets frontend developers mock out backend APIs.

Comment: `axios-mock-adapter` perfectly matches my specs !